# how to the the client request datetime and size of data sent to client in C?

Tags: c, proxy, client

I'm making a proxy program then needs to write to the log file. The data that I need is the datetime, how many bytes sent from the server, and hostname. I have problem in retrieve the datetime and the size of data. Anyone knows how to do this stuff?

Comment: But the other requirements you already implemented successfully?

Comment: yes, only those 2 that I have problem

Answer (score 0):

- For date and time functions see `man 7 time`.
- For hosts having connected to your server see the 2nd parameter of your server's `accept()` calls, pass the data received there to `getnameinfo()`, to resolve the address to a FQDN.
- For the amount of data transferred see the result of your server's `read()` calls.

Comment: for read() from the data read from the server, I found that the size if different from the size present on the header, is it right?

Comment: `read()` has no clue what kind of data is transfers, so  at least for TCP the amount the IP stack choses to transfer won't correlate to anything (like "headers" or whatever) defined by any application using such lowlevel calls.